# Large tables force page numbers into awkward locations

Tags: tables, geometry

I am trying to create a large table in landscape mode, but using the geometry package changes where the page numbers go. The result is a visually appealing table, but awkwardly placed page number. Does anyone know how to get both? I can break the table up as needed.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{caption}


\newcommand{\cocktail}[1]{\textbf{#1}\index{Cocktails!#1}}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page
    \else\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\cleartoleftpage}{%
    \clearpage
    \if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page
    \hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
    \if@twocolumn
    \hbox{}\newpage
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
}


\sloppy


\newgeometry{margin=1.5cm}
\begin{landscape}


\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Something Sweet and Sour}\label{sweetSour}%
    \begin{tabular}{l L{12em} L{12em}L{12em} L{10em}}
    \toprule
    Cocktail & Spirit & {Fruit juice} & {Sweetener} & Finishing touches \\
    \midrule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .929,  .929,  .929} \cocktail{Alabama Slammer} & {Southern Comfort,~0.75 oz} & {Orange juice, 2 oz} & Amaretto, 0.75 oz\newline{}Sloe Gin, 0.75 oz & {} \\[2em]
    \cocktail{Amaretto Sour} & Whiskey, 0.75 oz & {Lemon juice, 1 oz} & Amaretto, 1.5 oz\newline{}Simple syrup, 0.5 oz & Egg white\newline{}Angostura \\[2em]
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .929,  .929,  .929} \cocktail{Arrack Punch} & Batavia Arrack, 1.5 oz\newline{}Rum, 0.5 oz & Lemon juice, 0.75 oz\newline{}Pineapple juice, 0.5 oz & {Simple syrup, 0.75 oz} & Mint sprig\newline{}Seasonal berries \\[2em]
    \cocktail{Autumn in New Jersey} & Applejack, 2 oz & {Lemon juice, 0.75 oz} & {Orgeat, 0.75 oz} & Angostura\newline{}Mint sprig \\[2em]
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .929,  .929,  .929} \cocktail{Aviation} & Gin, 1.5 oz & {Lemon juice, 0.5 oz} & Luxardo, 0.75 oz \newline{}Cr\`{e}me de violette, 0.25 oz & Cherry or Lemon peel \\[2em]
    \cocktail{Batida de Coco} & Cacha\c{c}a, 1.5 oz & {Lime juice, 0.5 oz} & Cream of coconut, 1.75 oz & Grated nutmeg \\[2em]
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .929,  .929,  .929} \cocktail{Bees Knees} & Genever, 1.5 oz & {Lemon juice, 0.5 oz} & {Honey syrup, 0.75 oz} & Lemon twist \\[2em]
    \cocktail{Bella Luna} & Gin, 2 oz & {Lemon juice, 0.75 oz} & Elderflower liqueur, 0.75 oz\newline{}Cr\`{e}me de violette, 0.5 oz\newline{}Simple syrup, 1 tsp & {} \\[2em]
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .929,  .929,  .929} \cocktail{Blue martini} & Vodka, 0.75 oz & Lemon juice, 0.25 oz\newline{}Lime juice, 0.25 oz & Malibu coconut, 1 oz\newline{}Blue cura\c{c}ao, 0.5 oz\newline{}Simple syrup, 0.5 oz & Orange wheel \\[2em]
    \cocktail{Bramble} & Gin, 2 oz & {Lemon juice, 0.75 oz} & Cr\`{e}me de m\^{u}re, 0.5 oz\newline{}Simple syrup, 0.5 oz & Blackberry, lemon wheel \\[2em]
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .929,  .929,  .929} \cocktail{Cable car} & Spiced rum, 1.5 oz & {Lemon juice, 1 oz} & Orange liqueur, 0.75 oz\newline{}Simple syrup, 0.5 oz & Cinnamon rim\newline{}Orange twist \\[2em]
    \cocktail{Caipirinha} & Cacha\c{c}a, 2 oz & {Muddle 1 lime} & Simple syrup, 1 oz & {} \\[2em]



\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

[image: Table with awkwardly placed page number]
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3XKf.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Where yiz expect to be page number?

Comment: It should be spaced further inward at its default margin location. Right now, the page number is too close to the edge of the paper.

Comment: It is located according to set of `\newgeometry`. However, your table can be fit on one page if you are willing a wee bit to change it design without to change its page layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Page number is positioned according to this page layout.
- Since you are changed it by instruction

```
\newgeometry{margin=1.5cm}
```

it is placed according to new page layout.

- To have page number on the sam place as on the others pages, you need to remove this instruction and a wee bit redesign your table. For example, use smaller font size and prescribe table width.
- The table width you can specify in `tabular*`, `xtabular`, `tblr` (defined in the `tabularray` package) environments, etc.
- An example, how your table can be set by use of `rotating` and `tabularray` packages, is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{endnotes}  N not needed in this example
%\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Something Sweet and Sour}
    \label{sweetSour} 
    \small
\begin{tblr}{colsep=3pt,
             colspec={Q[l, font=\bfseries]
                      *{2}{X[l]} 
                      X[1.2, l]
                      X[0.8, l]},
             row{1}={font=\normalfont, c, m},
             row{even}={bg=gray!30},
             rowsep=3pt
             }
    \toprule
Cocktail    
    & Spirit & Fruit juice & Sweetener & Finishing touches  \\
    \midrule
{Alabama Slammer}
    & {Southern Comfort,\\ 0.75 oz}
        & Orange juice, 2 oz 
            & {Amaretto, 0.75 oz\\ Sloe Gin, 0.75 oz} 
                &                               \\
Amaretto Sour
    & Whiskey, 0.75 oz 
        & Lemon juice, 1 oz
            & {Amaretto, 1.5 oz\\ Simple syrup, 0.5 oz} 
                & Egg white Angostura           \\
Arrack Punch
    & Batavia Arrack, 1.5 oz Rum, 0.5 oz 
        & Lemon juice, 0.75 oz Pineapple juice, 0.5 oz 
            & Simple syrup, 0.75 oz
                & Mint sprig Seasonal berries   \\
{Autumn in\\
 New Jersey}
    & Applejack, 2 oz 
        & Lemon juice, 0.75 oz
            & Orgeat, 0.75 oz
                & Angostura Mint sprig          \\
Aviation
    & Gin, 1.5 oz 
        & Lemon juice, 0.5 oz
            & {Luxardo, 0.75 oz\\
               Cr\`{e}me de violette, 0.25 oz} 
                & Cherry or Lemon peel          \\
Batida de Coc
    & Cacha\c{c}a, 1.5 oz 
        & Lime juice, 0.5 oz
            & Cream of coconut, 1.75 oz 
                & Grated nutmeg                 \\
Bees Knees
    & Genever, 1.5 oz 
        & Lemon juice, 0.5 oz
            & Honey syrup, 0.75 oz
                & Lemon twist                   \\
Bella Luna
    & Gin, 2 oz 
        & Lemon juice, 0.75 oz
            & {Elderflower liqueur, 0.75 oz\\ 
              Cr\`{e}me de violette, 0.5 oz
              Simple syrup, 1 tsp}
                &                               \\
Blue martini
    & Vodka, 0.75 oz 
        & Lemon juice, 0.25 oz Lime juice, 0.25 oz 
            & Malibu coconut, 1 oz
              Blue cura\c{c}ao, 0.5 oz
              Simple syrup, 0.5 oz 
                & Orange wheel                  \\
Bramble
    & Gin, 2 oz 
        & Lemon juice, 0.75 oz
            & Cr\`{e}me de m\^{u}re, 0.5 oz
              Simple syrup, 0.5 oz 
                & Blackberry, lemon wheel       \\
Cable car
    & Spiced rum, 1.5 oz 
        & Lemon juice, 1 oz
            & Orange liqueur, 0.75 oz
              Simple syrup, 0.5 oz 
                & Cinnamon rim
                  Orange twist                  \\
Caipirinha
    & Cacha\c{c}a, 2 oz 
        & Muddle 1 lime
            & Simple syrup, 1 oz 
                &                               \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This was really helpful.

Comment: @RyanAycock, you are welcome. BTW, you may consider to accept answer (by clicking on check mark at top left side of the answer.)

Comment: I have a new problem. I changed your code to have each recipe on one line. Whenever I try to compile, I get the following error: "There are no entries found in a list you have created. Make sure you label list entries using the \item command, and that you have not used a list inside a table." The error line always points to \end{tblr}

Comment: @RyanAycock, sorry, I can't imagine, how you change my code. Please, ask new question, where you show your new not working code example (in form of complete small document). Than you will have more chance, that someone will help you.

Comment: I fixed it with `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}`. LaTeX keeps insisting that I am trying to use a list when I do not have one.

Comment: @RyanAycock, sorry, this site is not a forum. My answer hasn't any list. I do not know, where you inserted `minipage`, etc. Please (again), ask new question where explain what is your problem.